# Import only first line of multiple csv, dummycode repeats and calculate conditional probability

Tags: python, csv, statistics

I am actually a R savvy person but for this task I am using python and am overwhelmed by little things. I really hope you guys may help me.

I have three large csv files that contain ids in the first column. Each csv contains presence data of a day and each unique id stands for a person. csv1 is day 1, csv2 is day 2 and csv3 is day 3.

What I want to do now is to import only the first column for each csv because I don't need the rest and the files are quite big. Then I'd like to compare the appearance for each person (so the appearance for each id) and dummycode the information into one data frame where the first column contains the unique ids of all three csv files, the second a binary code for the presence of the id in the first csv (0=id doesn't appear in csv1, 1=id appaers in csv1) and then in column two do the same for csv2 and so on.

Last but not least, I'd like then to calculate the conditional probability for example for the case that a person that didn't came the first two days would show up on the third.

Of course a whole solution would be great but I would be pretty happy with baby steps and some python for dummies advice here, too. The thing is that I know how to do this with R but not with python and I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much and excuse my English.

If you need sample data, maybe this helps (the real data is huge):

```
    csv1
id col2 col3
1  x    x 
2  x    x
7  x    x

    csv2
id col2 col3
1  x    x 
3  x    x
7  x    x
4  x    x

    csv3
id col2 col3
1  x    x 
2  x    x
3  x    x
4  x    x
5  x    x
6  x    x
```

Dummycoded df would be:

```
    df
id csv1 csv2 csv3
1  1    1    1 
2  1    0    1
3  0    1    1
4  0    1    1
5  0    0    1
6  0    0    1
7  1    1    0
```

Comment: It's not clear that what you want to do with first column and after that, maybe you can clarify that by adding your code, or anything that you've tried so far.

Comment: I am sorry that its not clear what I want, where exactly cant you follow my explaination anymore? Maybe then I can clarify it with words. I cannot add any code because all I tried so far is as wrong as it can be, thats why I stay explanatory here. What I have are files like the csv1, csv2 and csv3, and what I want to do is generate df: a dataframe where I have one column for each csv showing whether the id appears in the id column of the file or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open your `csv` files and store all the first columns (ids) in a list:

```
with open(csv1_name) as f1, open(csv2_name) as f2,open(csv3_name) as f3:
    column1 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f1))) # in python 2 use zip(*csv.reader(f1))[0]
    column2 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f2)))
    column3 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f3)))
```

Now you have the indices of the items in new matrix that should be 1. So you can use a list comprehension to create your columns:

```
a = [[1, 2, 7], [1, 3, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
[[1 if j in a[i] else 0 for j in range(1, 8)] for i in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Or use `zip` again to create the rows:

```
In [138]: zip(*[[1 if j in a[i] else 0 for j in range(1, 8)] for i in range(3)])
Out[138]: [(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]
```

Note: if you don't know the maximum number of rows you can get that by flattening the columns list

So here is the general code:

```
from itertools import chain
import csv
with open(csv1_name) as f1, open(csv2_name) as f2,open(csv3_name) as f3:
    column1 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f1))) # in python 2 use zip(*csv.reader(f1))[0]
    column2 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f2)))
    column3 = next(zip(*csv.reader(f3)))

columns = [column1, column2, column3]
m_row = max(chain.from_iterable(a))
f_number = 3
new_columns = [[1 if j in columns[i] else 0 for j in range(1, m_row + 1)] for i in range(f_number)]

# Creating new csv file
with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    for id, row in zip(*new_columns):
        csvwriter.writerow((id,)+row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not quite sure what you do here, though. Where do you set that only the first columns are listed? And how do I build a? Maybe those questions are stupid but I don't see where you name the list "a". The ifelse statement sounds logical to me, though I don't really know what those ranges are supposed to mean.

Comment: @Marie-LouiseJournocode Actually the ranges are based on the number of your files (3) or the maximum number of rows.

Comment: ah ok, so for my actual data I have to choose a j range from 1 to the max number of rows and for i from 1 to the number of columns. So this is exactly like in R and I only got cinfused ba "range" :) Still it's not clear to me where you set that only the first columns are listed and where you name the list "a". Because a = [[1, 2, 7], [1, 3, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] is the resulting list but not the manually code to create it, right? Ah, you just edited! Sorry for being a python dummy :)

Comment: Ok now this (the general code) is something I really understand :D Thank you very much I am going to try this just now!